# PHP Form Submit Post creates temporary URL

Tags: php

When I submit my form on PHP, I wish to create a temporary URL containing the POST information from the PHP.  Also as there will be sensitive details, I also wish the link to auto-delete in 24 hours.
How can I achieve this? Any suggestions? I heard of using tokens but I am new to this.  Thanks

Comment: database holds data corresponding to a random generated unique string then htaccess used to map /example/uniquestring to default router/dispatcher to access the database data - ensure passwords are hashed - not encrypted and like stated above use an SSL connection

Comment: you will not benefit any thing from this because anyone can  submit the form but you can with session and token or another thing to specif who can submit and who can't ...for sensitive details  use ssl https to secure the user connection

Comment: I will then send the temporary URL for someone else to see the details

Comment: ok ..for temporary url you have two method to do this : 1) with create file and delete it later . 2) with one file and database

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not really sure what you mean by a temporary URL. Can you explain a bit more clearly what you want to achieve? Might be worth reading through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a random token for the filename. Create a [file](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp) with that name and output your data.

If you wanted to delete them after an *x* amount of time, you either need a function that is running all the time, or you can validate the file's age before outputting the content.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a router for that?

[https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router](http://Router%20PHP)

any router could help you to generate "dynamic" url. where the URL comes to a method parameter.

hope it gives you an idea.